# Moto X Pure Edition MetroPCS tethering

Tags: tethering, moto-x

Need help w Moto XPure Edition tethering on Metro. The plan I have came with tethering on there Phone but my Unlocked MXPE shows other devices connected but no internet connection. The lady at Metro says that because its not a metro phone but it is unlocked. Everything else worked but the tethering. What should I do? Do I need to root? Is there anyway to extract their Mobile hotspot app from my Metro phone and install on my Moto. I can't find it on the metro phone except on one of the screens and not the apps setting. Thanks Please help.
Rawfah

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-x-style/general/moto-x-pure-mvno-carrier-ting-vs-t3218182

One irritation with Ting was that tethering only worked on 3g. Which required manually setting the phone to 3g, after enabling the hotspot. You

MetroPCS in contrast does not allow tethering unless you purchase a metro branded phone.

I was able to work around the metro pcs tethering restriction by adding a "tether_dun_required=0" entry to the sqlite provider.settings file, and now it works perfect on LTE with the stock hotspot software.